# Job cannot finish draining because of no space left on device

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a streaming job running with 26GB memory and 4TB persistent disk.

The estimated size of input collection is 1.5GB, so I think the disk space should be enough.

But there are some logs on stackdriver like

`Warning: failed to write fluentd log output: write /var/log/dataflow/boot-json.log: no space left on device`

`[ERROR:serialization_utils.cc(302)] error writing message length: No space left on device`

`Failed to write position file, err: write /var/lib/agent/state/harness-boot.pos: no space left on device`

And this will cause the job cannot be drained successfully. The job will be stuck at draining forever.

It seems like there is nothing to do with persistent disk but boot disk?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? Running into the same problem and there seems to be no information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out that it was stuck at draining due to the data don't confirm to the schema of the BigQuery table I wanted to load to. There was no clear message though. I need to manually load the file dataflow generated to see the actual error message.

And the root cause is that when I want to write a string value `"null"` to a non-nullable string column in the table, somehow the value will be parsed as a `null` by Beam SDK and then it fails.